# Execute Sitecore workflow state actions using the API

Tags: api, workflow, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

I was wondering whether it's possible to execute Sitecore workflow actions via the API. I can't use the approach from here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Snippets/Workflow/Change%20the%20Workflow%20State%20on%20an%20Item%20via%20API.aspx (execute command that will trigger state change).

What I want is to programmatically create an item, and then set workflow state to "Awaiting for approval" for example, even if there is no command that has "Next Step" set to it.

Ideally, it would be something like

```
foreach (var action in awaitingForApprovalState.Actions)
{
  action.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use that approach? It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is the code that set the item state and executes actions which are in this state:

```cs
public void MoveToStateAndExecuteActions(Item item, ID workflowStateId)
{
    Sitecore.Workflows.IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Item.Database.WorkflowProvider;
    Sitecore.Workflows.IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);

    // if item is in any workflow
    if (workflow != null)
    {
        using (new Sitecore.Data.Items.EditContext(item))
        {
            // update item's state to the new one
            item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.WorkflowState] = workflowStateId.ToString();
        }

        Item stateItem = ItemManager.GetItem(workflowStateId, 
            Language.Current, Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest, item.Database, SecurityCheck.Disable);

        // if there are any actions for the new state
        if (!stateItem.HasChildren)
            return;

        WorkflowPipelineArgs workflowPipelineArgs = new WorkflowPipelineArgs(item, null, null);

        // start executing the actions
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.Start(stateItem, workflowPipelineArgs);
        if (pipeline == null)
            return;
        WorkflowCounters.ActionsExecuted.IncrementBy(pipeline.Processors.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tony It should work. You may want to use `item.Editing.BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit()` instead of `EditContext()`. All the rest of the code should be the same. Try and let us know.